# Вызвать SelectionIndicator в Cesium js

Tags: javascript

Требуется вызвать SelectionIndicator без нажатия на модель непосредственно, а по кнопке.
Подскажите с помощью чего это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел способ. Есть встроенная функция selectedEntity.
https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/Viewer.html#selectedEntity